# What nouns could symbolize a choice between 2 options?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, symbols, psychology

I want to name a process that has exactly two possible paths.  I'd like to give it a symbolic name.  These concepts come to mind but I'm hoping to think of others:

- coin flip
- double-edged sword
- window
- two-way mirror
- telephone / fax
- switch track (for trains)
- fork

I'd like the concept to be widely accessible / understood.  Ideally it would have a positive leaning toward it, as it will be used with medical patients.

What are some other objects / concepts that go two ways or have a choice of two paths?

Comment: *Binary* would be the word.

Answer (score 2):

*Fork* is the generally used metaphor. For medical patients especially, avoid *double edged sword* since that's a metaphor that means 'your weapon might cut you instead of your enemy'. Also *coin flip* suggests 'we don't know, really' which is probably not what you want.

Is there a reason you want a metaphor instead of just saying **choice**?

Comment: Although I like the word "choice" (especially since it also means "premium"), I'm trying to brainstorm other options because I bet there are other words that are more evocative (generate more visual and emotional meaning for someone and are "stickier" / easier to remember).